# PyQGIS update field in point layer from intersecting polygon

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, point

I have a large dataset of points and polygons layers.
My purpose is to update a field from each point with the id of the surrounding polygon.
It was possible to do it manually, using the field calculator and this formula :

```
array_to_string(overlay_within('polySample', polyID))
```

Now, having to process many files, my purpose is to do the same task using PyQGIS.
I tried with samples before looping through all the files, but it does not work :

```
pointPath = 'D:/.../pointSample.gpkg|layername=pointSample'
pointLayer = QgsVectorLayer(pointPath,"pointSample","ogr")
polyPath = 'D:/.../polySample.shp'
polyLayer = QgsVectorLayer(polyPath,"polySample","ogr")

provider = pointLayer.dataProvider()
idx = provider.fieldNameIndex('polyIDtoUpdate')
with edit(pointLayer):
    for feature in pointLayer.getFeatures():
        e = QgsExpression("array_to_string(overlay_within(polyLayer, polyID))")
        pointLayer.changeAttributeValue(feature.id(), idx, e.evaluate())
```

I am not sure of the syntax, especially regarding the QgsExpression part.

Can anyone give me some hints to write this part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the PyQGIS Developer Cookbook,

> "To evaluate an expression against a feature, a QgsExpressionContext
> object has to be created and passed to the evaluate function in order
> to allow the expression to access the feature’s field values."

https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#expressions-with-features

So in the case of your code above:

```
pr = pointLayer.dataProvider()
idx = pr.fieldNameIndex('polyIDtoUpdate')
str = "array_to_string(overlay_within('"+polyLayer.id()+"', polyID))"
e = QgsExpression(str)
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(pointLayer))
with edit(pointLayer):
    for f in pointLayer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        pointLayer.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), idx, e.evaluate(context))
```

As well as the PyQGIS Developer Cookbook, the following site is also useful when it comes to using expressions in PyQGIS:

https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis-101-using-expressions-to-compute-new-field-values/

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
I had read about the context and scope features but didn't actually understand how it could be applied. 
Your code and links helped a lot, an I could adapt it.